# Keep window in Mayavi after running python script

Tags: python, scipy, mayavi

I'm trying to run a python script that generates a plot using Mayavi.

I'm using the following example code to generate an iso-surface plot:

```
from mayavi import mlab
def test_contour3d():
    x, y, z = numpy.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, -5:5:64j]
    scalars = x * x * 0.5 + y * y + z * z * 2.0
    obj = mlab.contour3d(scalars, contours=4, transparent=True)
    return obj

test_contour3d()
```

The plot looks great but it immediately disappears. I [read](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/docs/guide/ch04.html) that you need to include the following code in order to make the plot stick around:

```
import mayavi
v = mayavi.mayavi()
v.master.wait_window()
```

This seems reasonable enough, but when I try this, python reports:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mayavi'
```

any ideas? I'm using the standard Enthought Python on OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mlab.show()`](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_other_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.show) to keep the plot frame open.

Comment: Well that was easy :)